# numberofSections method not getting called by [tableview reloadData]

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I am using `xcode 5.0.2`. Its a `UItabBarcontroller` with `2 tabs` with each `tab` having a `navigation controller` embedded programmatically in `App Delegate`. The problem might be a bit complex than it seems. I am using `UIStoryboard`. Is it something to do with autolayout being turned ON.

In `AppDelegate.m`

```
in didFinishLaunchingMethod
{
    self.tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    AIFirstViewController *viewController1 = [[AIFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    viewController1.title = @"Menu";

    AISecondViewController *viewController2 = [[AISecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    viewController2.title = @"Search";

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController1, navigationController2, nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:_tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

In the `firstViewController` for the first tab I wanted to display a `tableView`. I created a `IBOutlet` for the `tableView` and its `delegate and datasourc`e are connected to the file owner.

In `AIFirstViewConroller.m`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableVC.delegate = self;
    self.tableVC.dataSource=self;
    _checklist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5",  @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", nil];
    NSLog(@"the tableview object: %@", self.tableVC);
    [self.view addSubview:_tableVC];
    [self.tableVC reloadData];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.tableVC reloadData];
}

numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_checklist count];
}
```

The `tableView methods` are not getting called. Only the `viewDidLoad` gets called. What should I change?

The `second tab` has a `view-controller` which shows a `web-view`.
In the storyboard the segue is PUSH so I have to have a `Navigationcontroller` for the first VC.

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ: see 2nd line in viewDidLoad

Comment: Just a point: you dont need to do this:[self.view addSubview:_tableVC]; if you already have an IBOutlet from nib.

Comment: Do you have something like :@interface AIFirstViewConroller : UIView<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> in your .h file?

Comment: BTW, you are doing a lot of reloadData !!, you don't need to do that espically in viewDidLoad.

Comment: If you're using a storyboard, why are you using initWithNibName:bundle: to instantiate your controllers?

Comment: Dont try to reload in viewdidload and viewwillappear if you add tableview in xib then you will automatically reload the table while you are loading the view.Once remove those lines and check it once and check the object of tableview is connected properly are not.

Comment: I had deleted self.view addSubview:_tableVC  but the problem persists..

Comment: I have <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>  in .h file.

Comment: good point rdelmar.. do u think thats the problem because the 2nd tab is wokring fine displaying the webView.

Answer (score 2):

1) you don't require to add TableView as a subview (`[self.view addSubview:_tableVC]`) if you already put it in your related .xib file

2) Have you check, you linked the added table view (of your .xib) with your table view's instance method **tableVC**?

3) Have you include delegate, datasource headers in your .h file i.e. `<UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate>`?

4) You dont need to **reload** table view in **viewDidLoad**. You always do **reloadData** where your datasource of your table view is change.

5) Have you implemented delegate function **-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** to make your single cell according to your needs?

Comment: Hammy I had done all of the above , I dont think deleting the reloadData command will solve the issue.

Comment: @ShaluRaj any solution?